# Modify haskell function to run correctly

Tags: list, haskell, primes

I have the following haskell code:

```
a (b : bs) = b : [c | c <- (a bs), c `rem` b /= 0]
```

Can someone explain what this code does?
Running a as

```
a [3,5..42]
```

returns

```
  Prelude> a [3,5..42]
[3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41*** Exception: <interactive>:71:1-46: Non-exhaustive patterns in function a
```

From what i can see, the function works like the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The function considers b as a prime number and filters out the multiples of b. But i'm not really sure how. On top of that, the function throws this exception.

Comment: You should probably add a base case `a [] = []`.

Comment: Note that this function is probably *intended* to be run on an infinite list as in `a [2..]` or `a [3,5..]` in which case it generates an (infinite) list of primes without ever needing the base case.

Answer (score 6):

What you have here is a recursive function: You are calling `a bs` in your definition. Eventually bs will be the empty list, and at that point you get an exception. You can, for example, add the following line to your code:

```
a [] = []
```

Then the output will become:

```
[3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41]
```

As for what this function does, it returns every element in the list which is not a multiple of any previous element in the list. If you give it a list `[2..x]` where `x` is any integer, this is the same thing as a list of all prime numbers from `2` to `x`.

Another way of getting a list of primes is the one you've found:
You start from 3 and make the Haskell list comprehension skip any multiples of 2.

Comment: Minor point: I'd rather say "it generates" or "it outputs" than "it prints", since the function does not involve I/O on its own, it only returns the new list. (+1)